# How to identify unique matching records in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have one million XML documents like this in my MarkLogic staging database.

```
<Details>
  <Name>AA</Name>
  <EmpId>123</EmpId>
  <Account>
    <AccountNo>111</AccountNo>
    <IFSC>ABC</IFSC>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <AccountNo>222</AccountNo>
    <IFSC>DEF</IFSC>
  </Account>
</Details>
```

In this XML, an employee has multiple account numbers. From this, I want to identify any of the employees that have the same account number. Finding out unique account number from all 1M documents, and then check if the account number is matching to multiple employee ids.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way in which you can list all of the `AccountNo` values that appear in more than one employee document would be to use the [`cts:value-co-occurences()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-co-occurrences) method with references to an element range index of `AccountNo` and [`cts:uri-reference()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uri-reference) (which is available when the URI lexicon is enabled). Return the results as a map, with the `AccountNo` as the key and the document URI(s) as the value. Then filter the items in the map and report which `AccountNo` is associated with more than one document URI.

```
let $accountNumber-to-URI := 
  cts:value-co-occurrences(
    cts:element-reference(xs:QName("AccountNo")), 
    cts:uri-reference(), 
    "map")
for $accountNumber in map:keys($accountNumber-to-URI)
where tail(map:get($accountNumber-to-URI, $accountNumber))
return $accountNumber
```

Note that in order to be able to do this, you would need to have a range index on the `AccountNo` element.

Comment: How to restrict to collection level

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean when you say to restrict to collection level. If you want to restrict results to docs in a particular collection (or set of collections), then you can apply the 4th parameter after the "map" option, and specify a query, such as cts:collection-query() https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:collection-query

Comment: I am trying to check the combination (IFSC + Account No) as primary key, if this combination is coming same for different URIS, I need to get those URI's

Comment: An easy way would be to index the `Account` element (which contains both of those values) and use the same code in the answer, and then return the URIs by returning `map:get($accountNumber-to-URI, $accountNumber)`

Comment: I can index the Account element but its having more sub elements other than Account number and IFSC which I didn't mention in the above xml

Comment: Ah, okay. Then might need a different strategy